# jQuery: clone HTML with information from an array

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML that I want to repeat 5 times within a div container (.container).

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="name">Name</div>
   <div class="content>Content</div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery/JS, I want to create an array (or some other kind of organization structure), that when run through a for loop could CHANGE the 'Name' and 'Content' of each block.

For example, I have two arrays:

```
var names = ["Joe","Jane","Bill","Nicole","Dennis"];
var content = ["First content","Second content","Third content","Fourth content","Fifth content"]
```

I want to clone the top HTML and for each block, change the name and content to its respective array item. How can I do this?

Right now, I have the code to just repeat the HTML.

```
var row = $('.block');

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  $('.container').append(row.clone())
}
```

Edit: Is there a better way to do this without creating multiple arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` and `text` methods and change the content of elements before appending them, note that you are missing opening `{` for the `for` block.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   row.clone()
      .find('.name').text(names[i]).end()
      .find('.content').text(content[i]).end()
      .appendTo('.container')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SU3vF/

Answer (score 2):

I think here is your answer:

```
var row = $('.block');

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
  var cp = row.clone();
  cp.find('.name').text(names[i]);
  cp.find('.content').text(content[i]);
  $('.container').append(cp);
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pulkitm/NV2e2/